# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http'?

Tags: angular

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' even i used import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: your angular version

Comment: Try breaking the server by pressing Ctrl + C(on Windows) or Cmd + C(on Mac) and run the server again(`ng serve`)

Comment: try to npm install all your modules. Then make sure its actually in your node_modules folder inside of the @angular dependencies

Comment: Can you try `import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: Also you should put more information about your angular version

Comment: I did all these but did not work for me!! same error on console

Answer (score 5):

**in the root AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**In your Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getConfig() {
        return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
    }
}
```

**In your Components**

```
showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        // response...
    });
}
```

---

> **https://angular.io/guide/http**

---

Comment: I got working with these stufs but i got a new error while using.map((response: Response) => response.json())  error : TypeError: response.json is not a function

Comment: **import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';**

`getConfig() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl)
    .pipe(
        map((res: any) => res.json())
    );
}`

@Ganny

Comment: @Ganny did you `import { Response } from @angular/http`?

Comment: Yes I used this as well!

Answer (score 1):

`import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`- **Does not work**

Try the below one -

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
...
```

**This worked for me.**

Answer (score 0):

use`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`